# Why does the Java HashMap copy constructor affect floating point precision?

Tags: java, floating-point, copy-constructor

I had some code calculating a linear combination on maps of floats, and ran into an interesting side-effect of using the copy constructor.

If I calculate the linear combination of values in two maps and compare it with the linear combination calculated using the values in two *copies* of those maps, the calculations actually have slightly different (in the neighborhood of 10^-7) results due to what appears to be floating point precision.

Why does this happen?

Here's some sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class WTF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int c = 0; c < 1000; c++) {
            Map<String, Float> weights = new HashMap<String, Float>();
            Map<String, Float> values = new HashMap<String, Float>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                weights.put("sig" + j, Float.valueOf(rand.nextFloat()));
                values.put("sig" + j, Float.valueOf(rand.nextFloat()));
            }

            Map<String, Float> weightsCopy = new HashMap<String, Float>(weights);
            Map<String, Float> valuesCopy = new HashMap<String, Float>(values);

            float score1 = getScore(weights, values);
            float score2 = getScore(weightsCopy, valuesCopy);

            if (score1 != score2) {
                System.out.println(score1-score2);
            }
        }
    }

    public static float getScore(Map<String, Float> weights, Map<String, Float> values) {
        float score = 0.0f;
        for (String name : weights.keySet()) {
            Float weight = weights.get(name);
            Float value = values.get(name);
            score += weight.floatValue() * value.floatValue();
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The same issue also applies to the `putAll` operation. Using that to "copy" a `HashMap` results in the same floating point precision issues.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, specifically including the `for` loops.  Can you post a sample that compiles?  (I have a theory about the answer to the question, but I want to verify it first.)

Comment: Your code doesn't currently compile - both of the `for` loops in `main` are broken. (You're never *adding* anything to any maps, either...) Could you fix them, please?

Comment: You don't show the code that populates the maps.

Comment: The formatting is messed up, not the actual code, hit `edit` or find someone to approve my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order in the map is changing, causing the operations to be run in a different order.  An example of the output changing for simple computation (note the flipped d and e):

```
class WTF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final float a = 0.42890447f * 0.37233013f;
        final float b = 0.2648958f * 0.05867535f;
        final float c = 0.8928169f * 0.7546882f;
        final float d = 0.0039135218f * 0.59395087f;
        final float e = 0.9114683f * 0.33522367f;

        System.out.println(a + b + c + d + e);
        System.out.println(a + b + c + e + d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The iteration order is changing from the original maps to the copies, since it's rebuilding the hash table (probably with a different size).

The difference in the rounding comes from the fact that `*` and `+` on floats aren't *quite* commutative/associative, and you'll get different rounding errors depending on whether you do `a * (b * c)` or `(a * c) * b` or `(a * b) * c`.  Since the ordering of entries and keys is changing between the originals and the copies, you're getting tiny rounding differences in the results.

If you use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` to ensure preserved iteration order, you should get the exact same results each time.  (I've confirmed this on my machine.)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the float bits, you'll see one byte exponent and one mantisse bit (8 to the left) is swapped, so one bit error. (`2,384186e-07 34800000`)

```
            float ds = score1-score2;
            int bits = Float.floatToIntBits(ds);
            System.out.printf("%e %x%n", score1-score2, bits);
```

Answer (score 0):

The order you add floating point numbers can affect the result.  As HashMap doesn't guarantee any order so copying a HashMap can result in a different order, meaning the sum of values will be different.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random();
    float sum0 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        float f = rand.nextFloat() - rand.nextFloat();
        floats.add(f);
        sum0 += f;
    }
    floats.add(-sum0);

    SortedSet<Float> sums = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(floats, rand);
        float sum = 0;
        for (Float f : floats)
            sum += f;
        if (sums.add(sum))
            System.out.println(sum);
    }
    System.out.println("Unique sums count " + sums.size()
            + " from " + sums.first() + " to " + sums.last());
}
```

prints

```
1.8239021E-5
2.0623207E-5
-2.1278858E-5
1.847744E-5
2.18153E-5
  ....
-2.4557114E-5
-3.415346E-5
1.9788742E-5
-2.270937E-5
Unique sums count 795 from -3.4868717E-5 to 3.1232834E-5
```